# how do i reference the window associated with a nswindowcontroller

Tags: macos, nswindow, nswindowcontroller

I have a subclassof `NSWindowController` with an associated xib file. 
From my app delegate I display this using the following code:

```
if(!wc)
wc = [[NSWindowController alloc]initWithWindowNibName:@"MyNewWindowController"];

[wc showWindow:nil];
```

This displays the window. Now I want to reference that window in the new window controller but can't work out how. Specifically I have a button on the new window and I want to write something like:

```
- (IBAction)doStuffAndCloseWindow:(id)sender
{
  [self doSomeStuff];
  [*window* orderOut:nil];
}
```

I've tried creating a window variable (like the one created in appdelegate) but the compiler says my window variable is private.

So have do I declare and reference a window in my `MyNewWindowController.m`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Michael, see above, first declare your subclassed NSwindowController thus

```
@property IBOutlet MyNewWindowController *wc;
```

Then in the implementation of the subclassed window controller, you can refer to the associated window with

```
[[self window] .....];
```

For example

```
[[self window] orderOut:self];
```

Answer (score 0):

That would be the [`'window'` method of NSWindowController](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindowController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindowController/window).  It's also a property that you can access via "`.window`".

So, in the first code snippet, that would be:

`[wc window]`

and in the second code snippet (assuming "`doStuffAndCloseWindow`" is part of your subclassed NSWindowController):

```
- (IBAction)doStuffAndCloseWindow:(id)sender
{
  [self doSomeStuff];
  [[self window] orderOut:nil];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Yes the "doStuffAndCloseWindow" is part of my subclassed NSWindow controller. The code compiles ok but I get the following error message "Could not connect the action doStuffandCloseWindow: to target of class NSWindowController
". Which I don't understand as the File's Owner is of type MyNewWindowController (my subclass). Any thoughts?

Comment: In your storyboard or XIB file, you need to change the Custom Class of your window controller from NSWindowController to your subclassed "`MyNewWindowController`".

Comment: Thanks very much. It all makes sense now! Sorry I can't up vote your reply, I don't have enough kudos at the moment